# Low level JTAG Interface programming

Tags: jtag

What I have is direct access to the four JTAG Interface pins on an Atmel CPU.

What I need is low-level C code to wiggle those pins and implement two functions:

```
ReadMemoryWord(address)
WriteMemoryWord(address, word)
```

Anyone done this before? Or can point me in the right direction?

I already have one answer: Read the IEEE spec. I'm hoping there's a shorter path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look through [OpenOCD](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/). I'm not sure if it's a shorter path :)

Comment: I have been looking at OpenOCD and it has been helpful.